# Confirm box return value from alertify plugin and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, alertify

I have a confirm dialog for my form. it is inside a jquery submit function. I am using alertify to show the confirm dialog. But problem is my jquery submit function returns before alertify gets the confirm box value. Read that alertify is non blocking. Any way to overcome this and return the confirm box value back to my form?

```
$("#viewform").submit(function(){

      alertify.confirm("Delete the selected entry?",function(e){

             if(e)
                    return true;
              else 
                     return false;

               });


 });
```

The function always returns true. I want to return the output of confirm box. How can i return the delayed return value of confirm box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One work around would be to used a `button` rather than a `submit` input, then use a click listener to run alertify. This could then submit your form via jQuery. Here's how it might look:

HTML:

```
<form id="form">
    <input type="button" value="Submit" id="btn">
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#btn').click(function() {
    alertify.confirm("Delete the selected entry?",function(e){
        if(e) {
            $('#form').submit();
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. So we still need to return true or false? if(e){ $('#form').submit(); } would be enough right?

Comment: Yeah I don't think returning true or false would be necessary here. I just left it in for clarity.