# jQuery - Form submits before alertify receives confirm box value (with HTML5)

Tags: jquery, html, form-submit, confirm, required

I have a form with 2 fields, one of which is required. I used HTML5 **required** attribute to check if the field is filled up during submission.

```
<form id ='reg' name='reg' action='here.php' method='post'>
    <input type='text' id='name' name='name' placeholder='Name' value='' required="true" />
    <input type='text' id='contactno' name='contactno' placeholder='Contact No' value='' />
    <input type='submit' value='Register' name='register' id='register' /> 
</form>
```

Before the form actually submits, I want to show a confirm box (using **alertify** jQuery plugin) to prompt the user for a submission. If a user clicks OK, the form should submit. Otherwise, it should not. I used this code for the confirm box checking once the submit event fires:

```
$("#reg").submit(function() 
{
    alertify.confirm("Are you sure you want to commit your reservation?", function (e) 
    {
        if (e) {
            // user clicked "ok"
            alertify.success("You've confirmed your reservation.");
            return true;
        } else {
            // user clicked "cancel"
            alertify.error("You did not confirm your reservation.");
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Problem is, the form doesn't wait for the user's answer and submits immediately. I tried the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15876289/confirm-box-return-value-from-alertify-plugin-and-jquery), which seems ok at first. I replaced the html button type to 'button' and replaced the jquery code to this:

```
$("#register").click(function() 
{
    alertify.confirm("Are you sure you want to commit your reservation?", function (e) 
    {
        if (e) {
            // user clicked "ok"
            alertify.success("You've confirmed your reservation.");
            $("#reg").submit();
            return true;
        } else {
            // user clicked "cancel"
            alertify.error("You did not confirm your reservation.");
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

The problem with this one is that I have a required='true' attribute for one of the fields, which should prevent the form from submitting if the field is empty. The code above allows submission if the user clicks OK in the confirmation box even if the required field is still empty.

I want to check first if the field is filled up before it shows the dialog, then wait for the user's answer and then decide whether to submit it or not.  Any suggestions on how I could get this working? Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

prevent submit always, then manually submit the form on clicking ok.

```
$("#reg").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); // cancel submit
    alertify.confirm("Are you sure you want to commit your reservation?", function (e) {
        if (e) {
            // user clicked "ok"
            alertify.success("You've confirmed your reservation.");
            $("#reg")[0].submit(); // submit form skipping jQuery bound handler
        } else {
            // user clicked "cancel"
            alertify.error("You did not confirm your reservation.");
        }
    });
});
```

Also changed to a submit event rather than click as that's actually what you want, otherwise the required attribute is useless.

You rarely ever need to use a click event on a submit button. Just bind to the form's submit event.

Comment: Sorry to dredge this up... but I tried this and I am not getting the form to submit if the "ok" button is pressed. I tried it with and without the `[0]` and I even shoved another `event.preventDefault();` in after the `$("#reg")[0].submit();` line. Everything else is working, it just won't submit the form and redirect to the `action="whatever.php"` page to handle the processings.

Comment: If you can produce a fiddle showing the issue I'll look at it in the morning.

Comment: seems like this is as basic of a form as necessary: http://jsfiddle.net/wf7jhb9j/

Comment: never name a submit button "submit". Never name anything the same name of a domNode method or property.

Comment: doh & giggle... stupid lowercase/uppercase issue on my fat fingers... sigh, sorry to bother you. :headslap:

Comment: I will like to modify the code above, to fully show the alertify error or alert on cancel click.  $("#reg").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); // cancel submit
    alertify.confirm("Are you sure you want to commit your reservation?", function (e) {
        if (e) {
            // user clicked "ok"
            alertify.success("You've confirmed your reservation.");
            $("#reg")[0].submit(); // submit form skipping jQuery bound handler
        } 
    }, function(){alertify.error("You did not confirm your reservation.")});
});

Comment: @littleinstein Feel free to edit, if I disagree with the edit i can roll it back or modify it, ;)

Answer (score 0):

I modified the example above to reduce the boilerplate. No need for the bounds check override anymore. Just pass the event and message to the generic confirm() method.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    function confirm(event, msg) {
        var evt = event;
        event.preventDefault();
        alertify.confirm(msg, function (e) {
            if (e) {
                evt.currentTarget.submit();
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    $("#deleteApplianceForm").submit(function(event){
        confirm(event, "Are you sure you want to delete this appliance?");
    });
});
```